# Differences between Red's 5 function types, and why does it distinguish them?

Tags: rebol, red

In Red, there are functions of datatypes `function!`, `op!`, `native!`, `routine!` and `action!`. What are the differences between them? As far as I know `function!` is used for user-defined functions and `op!` for infix operators, and `routine!` for functions defined in `Red/System`, but why is there a need for the other two?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### `function!`

As you've guessed yourself, `function!`s are user-defined functions that support refinements and typechecking, and can also contain embedded docstrings.

Typically, `function!` values are created with `func`, `function`, `does` and `has` constructors, and utilize so-called *spec* dialect; but, in theory, nothing stops you from making your own constructors or devising your own spec formats.

It's also worth noting that `function!`s fully support reflection.

#### `op!`

`op!`s are infix wrappers on top of other 4 types of functions - they take one value on the left and result of an expression on the right, and they also take precedence other functions during evaluation.

`op!` values are limited to two arguments, don't support refinements, and have a limited support for reflection (e.g. you can't inspect their bodies with `body-of`).

#### `routine!`

`routines!` exist in both realms of Red and Red/System (low-level dialect on top of which Red runtime is build). Their specs are written in *spec* dialect, but their bodies contain Red/System code. Oh, and they support reflection.

Usually they are used for library bindings (like the SQL lib you've mentioned), interaction with runtime, or for performance bottlenecks (Red/System is a compiled language, so rewriting perfomance-critial parts of your app as a set of `routine!`s will give you a significant boost, at the cost of mandatory compilation).

#### `native!`

`native!`s are functions written in Red/System (for perfomance, simplicity or feasibility reasons) and compiled down to native code (hence the name). Not sure what else can be said about them, aside from implementation details. `native!` aren't very user-facing, so you might want to study Red's source code in case you have any questions left.

#### `action!`

`action!`s are a standardized set of function written in Red/System (just like `native!`s) that each datatype implements (or inherits) as its "method". `action!` are polymorphic in a sense that they dispatch on their first argument:

```
>> add 1 2%
== 1.02
>> add 2% 1
== 102%
>> append [1] "2"
== [1 "2"]
>> append "1" [2]
== "12"
```

In mainstream languages this typically looks like `"1".append([2])` or something like that.

Distinction between `action!`s and `native!`s boils down to a design choice:

- you can have as many `native!` as you want, but `action!`s, for efficiency, have a fixed-size dispatch table (which means that maximum number of `action!`s per datatype is limited; minimum number is two: `make` [to create value] and `mold` [to serialize value to `string!`]).
- logically, `action!`s are organized around datatype to which they belong, in one file, while `native!`s aren't really concerned with datatypes, and implement control flow, trigonometric functions, operations on sets, etc.

---

Coincidentially, just recently we have a [similar discussion](https://gitter.im/red/help?at=5cb598aebd70a40d5f5a6481) about `action!`s and `native!`s in our community chat, which you might want to read. I can also recommend to skim thru Rudolf Meijer's [Red specification](https://github.com/meijeru/red.specs-public/blob/master/specs.adoc) draft, and, of course, [official reference documentation](https://doc.red-lang.org/en/datatypes.html).

As for "why" in your question - distinction between 5 types is just an implementation detail, inherited from Rebol. Logically, they all implement what you might call a "function" from conceptual standpoint, and fall into `any-function!` camp.

Answer (score 3):

While to a caller it may seem similar to run a function whose body is a BLOCK! of code to one which is implemented as native instructions...the implementation has to go down a different branch.

I don't know precisely what Red does in the compilation case, the interpreter case for Rebol2 and Red are similar.  These different types are effectively part of a big switch() statement.  If it looks in the cell describing the "function" and finds TYPE_NATIVE it knows to interpret the cell's contents as containing a native function pointer.  If it finds TYPE_FUNCTION, it knows to pick apart the cell as containing a pointer to a block of code to execute:

https://github.com/red/red/blob/cb39b45f90585c8f6392dc4ccfc82ebaa2e312f7/runtime/interpreter.reds#L752

Now I myself would agree with your line of questioning.  e.g. is this leaking an implementation detail to the user--who shouldn't be concerned with this facet in the type system?

But for what it is worth, there is a catch-all typeset called ANY-FUNCTION!:

```
>> any-function!
== make typeset! [native! action! op! function! routine!]
```

And you might think of that as "anything that obeys a function-like interface for calling".  There are some complexities however, as OP! gets its first argument from the left...so that really is a matter of concern from an interface perspective.

Anyway... a NATIVE! (body is built as native code into the executable) vs. a FUNCTION! (body is a block of Red code run by interpretation or compilation) is just one distinction.  A ROUTINE! is a facade built to interact with a DLL/library [a la FFI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_function_interface) that did not have a-priori knowledge of Red.  An ACTION! is a very oversimplified attempt at what are called in other languages [Generics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generic_function).  An OP! just gets its first argument from the left.

Point being that each of these might feel the same to a caller (except OP!), but the implementation has to do something different.  The way it knows to do something different is via a type byte in a value cell.  That's how Rebol2 did it--and Red followed Rebol2 fairly closely--so that's how it also does it.  It means that any novel concept of what provides the implementation behind a function requires a new datatype, and it's probably not the greatest idea.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @nickkoro I feel I answered your original question ("Why does Red have 5 different types of functions?") better than the one you ultimately accepted, which adds the answer as a footnote (and glosses the difficulty of OP! when lumping these together).  But that's based on my reading.  If his answer was what you were looking for, then I changed the title of your question to match what he actually answered--where inventorying the function types and adding "why" as a footnote would have been appropriate.

Comment: You're right that the title is misleading, I'll change it. I was looking for an overview of the differences (which imho the accepted answer covers best) **and** for why this decisions where made (which you covered).

Answer (score 0):

Red is based on Rebol an so has the same types.

- **function!** is an user defined function defined in red
- **native!** is an function in machinecode
- **op!** is an infix operator written in machinecode
- **action!** is an polymorphic function in machinecode
- **routine!** is an function in imported from dynamic library

Comment: Thank you for your response, but I still not get the difference between a `native!` and a `routine!`. You can, in fact, write `routines!` yourself (have done that for a small private mysql lib) and they don't have to be imported. Futhermore, afaik you can define `op!` in interpreted Red to. And what do you mean by a "polymorphic function"?